# Chrome does not save Wordpress posts or page but IE does

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, custom-post-type

It is a bit of strange issue that I am facing with Wordpress and Google Chrome. When I edit a post or page, I am unable to save changes, chrome acts as if updating but keeps loading and never ends.

Also, sometimes I am unable to upload images too. I get http error. (please see attached image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8GIn.png

But when I use IE 11, I am able to save the post as usual. This happens very often and sometimes with Firefox too.

I used guest browsing to avoid conflicts with any plugins, but the result is still the same.

I uninstalled and reinstalled entire chrome, but no use. I disabled cache via inspect element panel but no use there too.

I am wondering what could be the issue. I would highly appreciate any help. Thank you.

**Steps I have taken**

- Used different identity in Chrome
- Used Incognito
- Used Guest Mode
- Disabled Cache and tried Disabled all extensions in Chrome
- Reinstalled completely by deleting entire Google Chrome folder on
  Apps folder after uninstall.

*My Chrome version is Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)* **(up to date)**

Comment: very rare, that IE can do something that firefox and chrome can't - Have you tried deactivating your plugins, and see if there is one that conflicts?

Comment: Yes, I did. But the result was the same. I also thought it may be the website and it 's script acting up. But, this is a same issue with few of the website that I deal with.

Comment: do you have javascript disabled? I have never heard of something like this before

Comment: No, JS is enabled. I think everything is as is provided by Google.

Comment: hit F12 and look at the log at the bottom right corner the next time you post. Any errors logged would show there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

After doing a lot of research and with a error clue of "**http error**" I understood something is blocking the communication between browser and server.

Then, I turned of Avast antivirus for 10 mins to check and it worked fine.
Now, I had to disable web shield and do all my editing.

So, if anyone get stuck like me, it would be Good to temporarily disable Anti-virus web shield or web protection and check.

Thanks for your suggestions @stender